# Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be a random variable, then $E[\max\{Z-1,0\}]$ is?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be a random variable, then $E[\max\{Z-1,0\}]$ is ?

I know by letting $\varphi$ be the standard normal density function and 
$X=\max\{Z-1,0\}$, we can simplify the expected value as
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = 0 \cdot \Pr(X=0) + \int_?^?  (z-1)\varphi(z)\,dz.
$$
I am not just sure about the integral part that have written and its limits.
Should it be the following?

$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = 0 \cdot \Pr(X=0) + \int_1^\infty  (z-1)\varphi(z)\,dz.
$$

Then how do we solve that?

Comment: Maybe use the addition rule for integrals... then note that $\int z\phi(z)$ is equal to something.

Answer (score 1):

Set $X=\max\{Z-1,0\}$ is positive a.s. and for $x>0$ we have

$$\mathbb P\{X>x\}=\mathbb P\{Z>x+1\}=\int_{x+1}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\mathrm d x,$$

Then, $$\mathbb E[X]=0\mathbb P\{X=0\}+\int_0^\infty \mathbb P\{X> x\}\,\mathrm d x=...$$

Comment: but how would you solve the integral? also $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ has left out.